# Why boolean returns undefined in Electron?

Tags: electron, node.js-fs

I want to print whether file exists or not in boolean but it keeps returning `undefined` in `renderer.js`. I use `fs` module with promises and I want to make this code print only `true` or `false`.

**main.js**

```js
ipcMain.handle('checkDbLocation', (event, databaseLocation) => {
  try {
    const stats = fs.stat(databaseLocation);
    return stats.isFile();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

**renderer.js**

```js
Button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  window.api.minimizeWindow();
  let result = await window.api.fsStat("C:\\Users\\workspace\\Downloads\\ChromeSetup.exe");
  window.api.log(result);
})
```

**preload.js**

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

const WINDOW_API = {
  log: (args) => console.log(args),
  fsStat: (databaseLocation) => {
    ipcRenderer.invoke('checkDbLocation', databaseLocation);
  }
}

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', WINDOW_API);
```

Comment: I will vote to close this question as caused by a typo. Your function `fsStat` doesn't return anything.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with electron, but aside from @Arkellys comment:  As the code currently is shown, your snippet of `main.js` will always go into the exception handling and thus never return a value., because you do not `await` the promise returned by `fs.stat()`. Thust `const stats` is not a `fs.Stat` but a `Promise<fs.Stat>` which doesn't have a `isFile()` method and thus throws an exception upon calling `stats.isFile()`

Comment: I made my code use promise and return false in catch block but it still does not work. Fs.isfile exist. https://nodejs.org/en/learn/manipulating-files/nodejs-file-stats. When I use console.log in main.js, it returns boolean. But when i use in renderer.js, it returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

[`fs.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsstatpath-options-callback) is an asynchronous function that accepts a callback to execute after the file stats have been received.

I suspect you're getting `undefined` because you're trying to access the `isFile()` method on `stats` which should be `undefined` itself. You're catching that exception and since you're not returning anything in the `catch` block, you're getting that `undefined`.

You may want to use instead [`fs.promises.stat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesstatpath-options) which is the promise based API for this method. You would need to make your handler `async`:

```js
ipcMain.handle('checkDbLocation', async (event, databaseLocation) => {
  try {
    const stats = await fs.promises.stat(databaseLocation);
    return stats.isFile();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

> Keep in mind that if for some reason `fs.promises.stat` rejects, the function will resolve to `undefined` because the `catch` block is not returning anything. You should probably add a `return false` at the end of the `catch` block to ensure that the function **always** resolves a `boolean`.

Another option, if you absolutely need this function to be synchronous, meaning that it should return a `boolean` and not a `Promise<boolean>` you could instead use the synchronous version of the method, [`fs.statSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsstatsyncpath-options), though it is not necessarily recommended to use it since it may block the thread and make your UI slightly unresponsive, depending on how big the file is and where you're calling this function.

Comment: This will still return `undefined` when the file doesn exist. Because `stat(...)` rejects on a path that doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, indeed that's the case. I refrained from putting a `return false` inside the `catch` because I figured that OP might want to handle error differently than file not found.  I'll edit in a little note mentioning that too. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to distinguish between "file does not exist" and "general error" you should inspect the error in the catch block. In case of a path not found, `stat()` throws a well documented `ENOENT` error. If you catch that specific error it's safe to assume that the path does not exist, and thus you can return `false`. Otherwise a different error occured and you could return `undefined`